# Finding all pairs of elements in an array that sum to a target value using multiple pointers (follow up)

Tags: c++, algorithm

The previous question was not clear enough so I will try to clarify it more in this follow-up question.
**I tried the multiple pointers technique to solve the problem that find pair of values that sums up to a target value.**

> **We are assuming that:**
>
> - **the array is already sorted.**
> - **we are working with a static array of size 16 (testing purpose only).**
> - **we are not working with actual pointers; because we don't need them in this case (I think), I named the question on the algorithm's
>   name only.**

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector> 
using namespace std;

struct result
 {
     int num1;
     int num2;
     result() {}

     result(int num1, int num2)
         : num1{ num1 }, num2{ num2 } {}
 };

 vector<result> mult_pt(int arr[], int target)
 {
     int p1 = 0;
     int p2 = 15;
     bool flag = false;
     vector<result> res;
     while (p1 <= p2)
     {
         if (arr[p1] + arr[p2] == target)
         {

             for (int k = 0; k < res.size() - 1; k++)
             {
                 if (res.size() == 0)
                     res.push_back(result(arr[p1], arr[p2]));
                 else if (res[k].num1 != arr[p1] && res[k].num2 != arr[p2])
                 { 
                     flag = false;
                 }
                 else flag = true;
             }
             if(flag) res.push_back(result(arr[p1], arr[p2]));
             p1++;
         }
         else if (arr[p1] + arr[p2] < target)
         {
             p1++;
             continue;
         }
         else if (arr[p1] + arr[p2] > target)
         {
             p2--;
             for (int i = p1; i >=0; i--)
             {
                 if (arr[i] + arr[p2] == target)
                 {
                     res.push_back(result(arr[p1], arr[p2]));
                 }
                 else if (arr[i] + arr[p2] > target)
                 {
                     continue;
                 }
                 else break;
             }
         }
     }
     return res;
 }

int main ()
{
  int array[16] = { 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};
  vector <result> res = mult_pt(array, 19);
  for (int j = 0; j < res.size(); j++)
    {
        cout << "[ " << res[j].num1 << " , " << res[j].num2 << " ]" << endl;
    }
  return 0;
}
```

**The output should be like:**

```
[ 4 , 15 ]
[ 5 , 14 ]
[ 6 , 13 ]
[ 7 , 12 ]
[ 8 , 11 ]
[ 9 , 10 ]
[ 10 , 9 ]
```

**You can check the previous post** [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/260174/finding-all-pairs-of-elements-in-an-array-that-sum-to-a-target-value-using-multi).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding all pairs of elements in an array that sum to a target value using multiple pointers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/260174/finding-all-pairs-of-elements-in-an-array-that-sum-to-a-target-value-using-multi)

Comment: I don't think this question adds anything new to the previous one so I vote to close as duplicate.

Comment: @slepic The edit in the previous question [was rolled back](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/260174/finding-all-pairs-of-elements-in-an-array-that-sum-to-a-target-value-using-multi#comment513770_260174), so that would be going in circles.

Comment: You didn't seem to apply the advice that was given when you asked the first time.

Comment: I have clarified the question because it was not clear and I didn't get the answers I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### `using namespace std;`

There are lot of good answers why you shouldn't use it. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

---

### Use `std::pair<int, int>`

Since your `result` struct is just acting as a container for two `int`s, consider using `std::pair<int, int>`

---

### Don't hardcode values

Why do you want hardcode `16` as the array length? You can just pass it to the function as a parameter, or use `std::array`. Your code should be able to handle any number of elements.

---

### `while(p1 <= p2)`

This is incorrect. This will allow the algorithm to run for single length arrays as well. For example, consider the array `{7}` and target value 14. Your code returns `{7,7}` as an answer. In fact, the rogue `[10, 9]` in your output is a direct result of this.

---

### Comparison of signed and unsigned ints

If you turn on warnings `-Wall -pedantic`, you will see your compiler warn you about comparing signed and unsigned ints. For example, comparing `k` which is a signed int to `res.size() - 1` which is an unsigned int.

In fact, you're quite lucky that the first time you encounter a valid pair, it's inserted into the result vector. `res.size() - 1` wraps around to whatever the maximum value of `vector<result>::size_type` is (in my case, 18446744073709551615) which means `k < res.size() - 1` is valid.

In fact, you don't even need this entire loop (see below).

### Use curly braces consistently

Your use of curly braces is very inconsistent. As a general use, always use curly braces for your conditional statements. It looks cleaner and can help avoid subtle bugs.

---

Since you're using `arr[p1] + arr[p2]` quite a bit, better to use a variable to store the value.

---

`if(res.size() == 0)` is irrelevant because it's always gonna be `false` (ignoring that one case at the very beginning because it's poor code, not an edge case to be handled).

---

I'm still not quite sure what the `flag` variable is mean to do. All your inner loop is doing is looking at the second to last element in the res vector and comparing values. `flag` will never be true unless the second to last element in the res vector has elements matching `arr[p1]` and `arr[p2]`.

---

You have needlessly complicated your algorithm (the inner loop inside of the `else if` block, for example).

In pseudocode, this algorithm can be written as:

```
while(p1 < p2)
      sum = array[p1] + array[p2]
      if sum == target
           insert into res vector
           p1++
           p2--
     else if sum < target
           p1++
    else
           p2--
```

---

You could use `res.emplace_back(arr[p1], arr[p2]);` instead of `res.push_back(result(arr[p1], arr[p2]));`. The former constructs the struct in-place, while the latter might invoke the move constructor.

Comment: The inner for loop is a big mistake, that's true, I was checking if the found pair is already in the results vector, but we don't need that since we are working with a sorted array.